# How to insert line break after every 80 characters

Tags: javascript

I have a very long string.

I want to append `<br/>` after every 80 characters so it can displayed nicely in the inner HTML.

Is there any easy way?

Comment: Use _String.substring()_...  You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: can u do it with css ??

Comment: seems that you are trying to replace css with javascript

Comment: yes arun i could do with css using 'word-wrap: break-word;'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do it with `long_string.replace(/(.{80})/g, "$1<br>");`

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2YJp/

Answer (score 12):

Here's the academic edition (it's also [faster than regex](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-recursive-fold-string)):

```
function fold(input, lineSize, lineArray) {
    lineArray = lineArray || [];
    if (input.length <= lineSize) {
        lineArray.push(input);
        return lineArray;
    }
    lineArray.push(input.substring(0, lineSize));
    var tail = input.substring(lineSize);
    return fold(tail, lineSize, lineArray);
}
```

Usage:

```
var arrayOfLines = fold(longString, 80);
var foldedString = arrayOfLines.join('<br/>');
```

- [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/Rwr7q/18/)
- [Performance Comparison vs Regex](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-recursive-fold-string)

---

Another thing that's cool about this approach: you can easily wrap at whitespace.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/Rwr7q/18/) that does that.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/(.{1,80})/g, '$1<br/>')
```

You could also just set the width of the containing element of the text to be `80em`. (it won't fit *exactly* 80 characters since an `em` is the width of the letter `m`, so you might want to set it a bit lower)

Comment: It won't fit exactly 80em... unless, of course, he uses a monospace font (did you copy my answer? :P jk, I know is the straightforward answer)

Comment: @chris That's what I said in my answer. Also no I didn't copy your answer, I'm answering from an iPhone so I can't see new answers as they get posted and I type slow `:P`

Comment: @chris - It's not copying when there's one straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

replace `0,1` with `0,80` and join('is') with `'<br />'`

```
console.log("google is very fast".match(new RegExp(".{0,1}", "g")).join('is'));
```

Comment: I'm very curious why you did your example like that.

Why in your example you use `0,1` and `is` and then added the instruction to replace them with `0,80` and `<br/>`, *instead of just using the `0.80` and `<br/>` in the example itself?*

Comment: @chris-l I dont actually remember . But i think I might have tried my self and pasted there directly .

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast solution, you can use this algorithm:

```js
function textFold(input, lineSize) {
  const output = []
  let outputCharCount = 0
  let outputCharsInCurrentLine = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const inputChar = input[i]
    output[outputCharCount++] = inputChar
    if (inputChar === '\n') {
      outputCharsInCurrentLine = 0
    } else if (outputCharsInCurrentLine > lineSize-2) {
      output[outputCharCount++] = '\n'
      outputCharsInCurrentLine = 0
    } else {
      outputCharsInCurrentLine++
    }
  }
  return output.join('')
}

document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = textFold('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 10)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Input:

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Output:

```
0123456789
abcdefghij
klmnopqrst
uvwxyz
```

Comment: How can I add CSS styles? let's say I want to align center.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript variant of [jahroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17895228/574736) answer:

```
export class FrameworkUtil {

    public static foldText(text: string, charCount: number, buildArray: string[] = []) {
        if (text.length <= charCount) {
            buildArray.push(text);
            return buildArray;
        }
        let line = text.substring(0, charCount);
        const lastSpaceRgx = /\s(?!.*\s)/;
        const idx = line.search(lastSpaceRgx);
        let nextIdx = charCount;
        if (idx > 0) {
            line = line.substring(0, idx);
            nextIdx = idx;
        }
        buildArray.push(line);
        return FrameworkUtil.foldText(text.substring(nextIdx), charCount, buildArray);
    }
}
```